# upgrading plone 2.x to 4x

Tags: plone

I would like to upgrade my site from plone version 2.55 to 4.x. I know I probably have to upgrate the site from plone 2x to 3x and then from 3x to 4x. Would this be a recommended solution?. Or is it better to start with a fresh install of 4.2, installing add-ons and then migrating files and content via FTP?. Thoughts and comments will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This very much depends on your add-ons you have used on the site. Either the add-ons themselves could be problematic (no 4.2-compatible versions available) or the data they manage is not updated to follow changes in the updated add-on.

Mostly, though, an upgrade from 2.5 all the way to 4.2 should be fine; try it directly on a 4.2 install (copy over the Data.fs, install compatible versions of your add-ons, upgrade), or use a 3.x intermediary version.

The [Plone Upgrade Guide](http://plone.org/documentation/manual/upgrade-guide/) documents the process in detail.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. I should probably configure all the add-ons again. Can you add a little more detail on how to upgrade i

Comment: There you go; the process is well documented on the Plone website.

Comment: It has a lot of useful information. I will try upgrading it and get back to you on this. Thank you so much

Comment: Try also http://opensourcehacker.com/2011/06/01/plone-4-upgrade-results-and-steps/